# If specific element is display, change css of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a slider image running with bootstrap. I would like, depending of the slide being display, to change the CSS of another div.

For example, if Slide (item in the class) is display, my other div get a margin-left of 50px, if Slide 2 is displayed (active), the other dive get a margin-left of 100px

I tried the following jQuery without success:

```
if (!$('.item.one').is(':visible')) {
    $(".result").css("margin-left", "50px");
};
```

If anybody has any advice it would be fantastic! Thanks in advance.

-- EDIT --

Here my Html:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item one active">
        <img style="width:500px" src="assets/images/pattern/04.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item two">
        <img style="width:500px" src="assets/images/pattern/02.png">
    </div>
     <div class="item three">
         <img style="width:500px" src="assets/images/pattern/03.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item four">
        <img style="width:500px" src="assets/images/pattern/01.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="result" class="result">
    <img src="assets/images/silouhette.png" alt="Silhouette placeholder">
</div>
```

I have change by the following Jquery from Poonan:

```
if (!$('.item.one').is(':visible')) {
    $(".result").css("margin-left", "50px");
};
if (!$('.item.two').is(':visible')) {
    $(".result").css("margin-left", "150px");
};
if (!$('.item.three').is(':visible')) {
    $(".result").css("margin-left", "250px");
};
if (!$('.item.four').is(':visible')) {
    $(".result").css("margin-left", "350px");
};
```

This apply fine - but If I change to item one - it keep the css from item four of the Jquery . . .. anyway that it changes when I change the slide do you think ???

-- Bootsrap slider settings --

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    pause: true,
    interval: false
});
```

Comment: give a unique `id` to the slider not `class`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/6bt8dy64/

Comment: Do you have `slide-changed` event ?

Comment: Your code only runs once. You need it to run each time the slider slides :p

Comment: Thx Poonam, this work, I have updated my question with all the code, now the problem is when I change slide, it doesn't change the css . . what ever is the slide being display ( 1 2 3 or 4) it take the code of item4 jquery . . . 

Any advise guys ? Will be awesome :)

Comment: Where's the code that kicks off the slider?

Comment: Just added, I m calling it via Bootstrap

Comment: I don't get it, only one item is active, shouldn't `!$('.item.one').is(':visible')` be `$('.item.one').is(':visible')` ?

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] using the built in snippet/jsfiddle etc with some dummy images we can play with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead (event when it has slided):

```
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
  if ($('.item.one.active').length > 0) {
    $(".result").css("margin-left", "50px");
  };
  if ($('.item.two.active').length > 0) {
    $(".result").css("margin-left", "150px");
  };
  if ($('.item.three.active').length > 0) {
    $(".result").css("margin-left", "250px");
  };
  if ($('.item.four.active').length > 0) {
    $(".result").css("margin-left", "350px");
  };
});
```

See this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/bp9n4whw/3/)

Comment: `slid` or `slide`?

Comment: `slid`, `slide` is before it has slided.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for us to try?

Comment: @tibewww See update, try with `slid.bs.carousel` for bootstrap 3.

Comment: just tried, stil the same :( Thanks for your help, Im going to post a fiddle with the link, this way it will be better I suppose

Comment: @tibewww Linked to a working fiddle using `slid.bs.carousel` event.

Comment: You re amazing !!!

Im just wondering why its not working on my side when i put the same code from you :( Im using bootstrap 3.3.6, I also used your Html and the .result doesnt move at all now :( :( :(

Comment: Can't really know why it's not working for you unless you provide your own fiddle that doesn't work, for me to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo out, hopefully it's what you search for, it would be better if you'd create a basic yet working fiddle. Anyway, you can use `.hasClass("active")` to check if a specific item is active and change the margin accordingly.

```js
fixMargin();

function activate(){
 $('.item').removeClass('active');
  var item = $('#selector').val()-1;
  $('.item:eq("'+item+'")').addClass("active");  
 fixMargin();
}

function fixMargin(){
  if ($('.item.one').hasClass("active")) {
  $(".result").css("margin-left", "50px");
  };

  if ($('.item.two').hasClass("active")) {
  $(".result").css("margin-left", "150px");
  };


  if ($('.item.three').hasClass("active")) {
  $(".result").css("margin-left", "250px");
  };

  if ($('.item.four').hasClass("active")) {
    $(".result").css("margin-left", "350px");
   };
}
```

```css
#selector{
  width:20px;
}
.one {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Make item<input id="selector" type="text" value='2'/>(type number 1-4) active <button onClick="activate()">now</button></br/>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

<div class="item one active">
             <img style="width:500px" src="assets/images/pattern/04.jpg">

</div>
<div class="item two">
             <img style="width:500px" src="assets/images/pattern/02.png">

</div>

 <div class="item three">
             <img style="width:500px" src="assets/images/pattern/03.jpg">

</div>

 <div class="item four">
             <img style="width:500px" src="assets/images/pattern/01.jpg">

</div>

  </div>

    <div id="result" class="result">

        <img src="assets/images/silouhette.png" alt="Silhouette placeholder" 
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`if (!$('.item.one').is(':visible'))`

use

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if ($('.item.one').hasClass('active')){
        $(".result").css("margin-left", "50px");
    }
    if ($('.item.two').hasClass('active')){
        $(".result").css("margin-left", "50px");
    }
    if ($('.item.three').hasClass('active')){
        $(".result").css("margin-left", "50px");
    }
    if ($('.item.four').hasClass('active')){
        $(".result").css("margin-left", "50px");
    }
}, 5000); // 5000 is the default interval
```